# Most Active Contributors Monthly Report - January 2018

Tags: discussion, most-active-contributors, announcement

## Welcome to the fourth edition of the monthly Ask Different Most Active Contributors Report.

This report will be published Monthly / Quarterly / Yearly. Please don't hesitate to share your valuable feedback in the comments.

This month we have included some minor refinements to the report:

- where possible, we now indicate the total number of users who participated in each category
- the scoring formula now allows for the possibility of users ranking more than once in the 'Highest Voted' or 'Most Viewed' categories.

[image: TITLE: REPORT TITLE]

### Report for January 2018

This report includes the following sections:

1. Overall Most Active Contributors Award
2. Monthly Reputation Leader Board
3. Most Active Editors Award
4. Most Active Voters Award
5. Most Close Votes Reviewed Award
6. Most First Posts Reviewed Award
7. Most Late Answers Reviewed Award
8. Most Low-Quality Posts Reviewed Award
9. Most Reopen Reviews Award
10. Most Suggested Edits Reviewed Award
11. Highest Voted Questions Award
12. Highest Voted Answers Award
13. Most Viewed Questions Award
14. Ranked 1st Summary List
15. Moderators Activity Summary

---

[image: TITLE: OVERALL MOST ACTIVE CONTRIBUTORS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                    SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   grgarside                  325
2   JMY1000                    300
3   Allan                      285
4   patrix                     200
5   klanomath, Monomeeth       160
```

**Note:** This is an overall ranking based on all activities. Maximum possible score = 850.

---

[image: TITLE: MONTHLY REPUTATION LEADER BOARD]

[image]

A total of 1,641 users earned reputation during the month. You can view the full list [here](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/118/month/apple/2018-01-02).

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE EDITORS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  EDITS
---------------------------------------
1   grgarside                120
2   klanomath                 75
3   patrix                    39
4   bmike                     36
5   Allan                     35
```

A big thank you to all 20 users who edited questions or answers this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE VOTERS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  VOTES
---------------------------------------
1   PeterJ                  1,853
2   Monomeeth                 803
3   LangLangC                 244
4   if....                    194
5   grgarside                 190
```

A big thank you to all 64 users who voted on questions or answers this month!<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1. Note: Only users who have voted at least 10 times in the period are counted in this metric.</sup>

---

[image: TITLE: MOST CLOSE VOTES REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   patrix                    73
2   JMY1000                   52
3   Allan                     45
4   Scot                      44
5   grgarside                 38
```

A big thank you to all 20 users who reviewed Close Votes this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST FIRST POSTS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   JMY1000                  248
2   patrix                   151
3   Scot                     117
4   grgarside                 83
5   pjc90                     76
```

A big thank you to all 40 users who reviewed First Posts this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST LATE ANSWERS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   JMY1000                   69
2   Allan                     64
3   Scot                      40
4   pjc90                     23
5   grgarside                 21
```

A big thank you to all 24 users who reviewed Late Answers this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST LOW-QUALITY POSTS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   JMY1000                   60
2   Scot, Allan               36
3   Tetsujin                  31
4   pjc90                     21
5   IconDaemon                13
```

A big thank you to all 23 users who reviewed Low-Quality Posts this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST REOPEN POSTS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   JMY1000                  18
2   patrix                   17
3   Allan                    11
4   Tetsujin, fsb             7  
5   IconDaemon                6
```

A big thank you to all 14 users who reviewed Reopen Votes this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST SUGGESTED EDITS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   techraf                  63
2   JMY1000                  37
3   Allan                    31
4   Scot                     26
5   grgarside                22
```

A big thank you to all 41 users who reviewed Suggested Edits this month!

---

[image: TITLE: HIGHEST VOTED QUESTION AWARD]

1. [What causes a random giant mouse cursor?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/312821/what-causes-a-random-giant-mouse-cursor)

   - Posted by: Mr. Boy
   - Votes: **21**
2. [Is there a Meltdown vulnerability fix already available for macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/311197/is-there-a-meltdown-vulnerability-fix-already-available-for-macos)

   - Posted by: rraallvv
   - Votes: **15**
3. [Before putting an iPhone5 into very long-term storage should I fully drain battery?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/310978/before-putting-an-iphone5-into-very-long-term-storage-should-i-fully-drain-batte)

   - Posted by: Khae
   - Votes: **11**

---

[image: TITLE: HIGHEST VOTED ANSWER AWARD]

1. [What causes a random giant mouse cursor?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/312821/what-causes-a-random-giant-mouse-cursor/312822#312822)

   - Answered by: grgarside
   - Votes: **48**
2. [Before putting an iPhone5 into very long-term storage should I fully drain battery?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/310978/before-putting-an-iphone5-into-very-long-term-storage-should-i-fully-drain-batte/310980#310980)

   - Answered by: Monomeeth
   - Votes: **19**
3. [What affects the colour of the Startup Screen?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/313246/what-affects-the-colour-of-the-startup-screen/313249#313249)

   - Answered by: grgarside
   - Votes: **16**

---

[image: TITLE: MOST VIEWED QUESTION AWARD]

1. [What causes a random giant mouse cursor?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/312821/what-causes-a-random-giant-mouse-cursor)

   - Posted by: Mr. Boy
   - Views: **3,727**
2. [Before putting an iPhone5 into very long-term storage should I fully drain battery?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/310978/before-putting-an-iphone5-into-very-long-term-storage-should-i-fully-drain-batte)

   - Posted by: Khae
   - Views: **2,793**
3. [macOS High Sierra 10.13.2 briefly flashes screen content last seen before locking the screen when awaken](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/312294/macos-high-sierra-10-13-2-briefly-flashes-screen-content-last-seen-before-lockin)

   - Posted by: Sarge Borsch
   - Views: **2,539**

---

[image: TITLE: RANKED 1st SUMMARY LIST]

**1.    Overall Most Active Contributors Award**

- [grgarside](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/37797/grgarside)

**2.    Monthly Reputation Leader Board**

- [grgarside](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/37797/grgarside)

**3.    Most Active Editors Award**

- [grgarside](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/37797/grgarside)

**4.    Most Active Voters Award**

- [PeterJ](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/83841/peterj)

**5.    Most Close Votes Reviewed Award**

- [patrix](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/9058/patrix)

**6.    Most First Posts Reviewed Award**

- [JMY1000](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/140612/jmy1000)

**7.    Most Late Answers Reviewed Award**

- [JMY1000](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/140612/jmy1000)

**8.    Most Low-Quality Posts Reviewed Award**

- [JMY1000](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/140612/jmy1000)

**9.    Most Reopen Reviews Award**

- [JMY1000](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/140612/jmy1000)

**10.   Most Suggested Edits Reviewed Award**

- [Techraf](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/145449/techraf)

**11.   Highest Voted Questions Award**

- [Mr. Boy](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/38485/mr-boy)

**12.   Highest Voted Answers Award**

- [grgarside](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/37797/grgarside)

**13.   Most Viewed Questions Award**

- [Mr. Boy](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/38485/mr-boy)

---

[image: TITLE: MODERATORS ACTIVITY SUMMARY]

In January our [Moderators](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) actioned 452 flags with an average handling time of 13 minutes. In summary, we also:

- deleted 182 comments
- deleted 332 posts
- closed 215 posts
- edited 234 posts
- created 128 posts
- created 418 comments

---

Please join me in thanking all contributors for volunteering their time to make this site so great. We appreciate the contributions made by all users, not just those listed in this report!

Keep up the great work! :)